# Is there any benefit to using Total Defense when a character has Combat Expertise?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I can't see any good reason for someone to use [Total Defense](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#totalDefense) when they have [Combat Expertise](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#combatExpertise).  If I understand correctly, using Combat Expertise the character (assuming a BAB of 4 or higher) could have a +4 dodge bonus to armor class, while receiving a -4 penalty to all attacks.  Using Total Defense, that same character would receive the same bonus to AC, but would have to give up all attacks.

Comment: You may be interested in the fact that you may combine Combat Expertise with Fight Defensively attack option (but not with Total Defence).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why should an option that's available to everyone be as or more beneficial than a similar option that's available only to those who spend resources to acquire it?

Comment: @HeyICanChan - That assertion is not in the question? The point is that one option essentially supersedes the other for most circumstances, but without ever mentioning it.

Comment: …Except that the entry on total defense does say it can't be simultaneously with the feat Combat Expertise. I dunno. Maybe I'm just not seeing it. To me, the question seems to ask *Why would I use X if X+1 is better?* And, while I'm *not* saying that's *not* a valid question, I am wondering if there's a way to phrase it that doesn't seem to beg for an answer like *Because X+1 is better.*

Comment: Try, *Why would I use option B if option A is better that option B when I add skill Z?* That's pretty much what it says. It reads to me like whoever wrote Combat Expertise, Fighting Defensively and Total Defense weren't on the same page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In theory, a character with a BAB lower than +4 would see a larger AC bonus from Total Defense than from Combat Expertise. Once BAB +4 is attained, Combat Expertise is strictly superior.

However, both options are exceedingly poor. Situations dire enough to give up offensive capability completely, or severely hamper it, should generally be responded to by *retreating*, not trying to “turtle.” That maneuver is only appropriate when cornered **and** help will arrive **very** soon (1 round, *maybe* 2). Since this is situation every character should be actively trying to avoid as much as possible, Total Defense is superior to Combat Expertise simply because **you don’t need to have planned on getting into that situation** in order to use it. Because you should be avoiding that situation as much as you can, spending a feat on a situation that occurs rarely and you are actively avoiding is unwise. The attacks you make at a −5 penalty are just not worth a feat, nor is the +1 to AC.

If you are concerned about this situation, and *want* to spend resources on handling it, it is far, far better to invest in a “panic button” that can get you *out* of such a situation. *Anklets of translocation* provide two swift-action, 10-ft. teleports a day for a measly 1,400 gp. That’s worth **way** less than a feat, and will go a long way to making sure you never *have* to turtle in the first place.

Unfortunately, that argument is moot in a lot of cases because characters are forced to acquire Combat Expertise because of its frequent use as a feat tax. Once you’ve got it (and BAB +4 or more), there’s no reason **not** to use it if you find yourself in a situation where you have to turtle. You should still have panic buttons, and should still use them first, of course.

Comment: Useful commentary. Too bad Combat Expertise didn't include the opposite (trading an AC penalty for an attack bonus).

Comment: @Wyrmwood That would be one of the best fighter feats in the game, if it existed. Particularly if it were uncapped, à la Power Attack. Consider Shock Trooper, which requires Improved Bull Rush (not a valuable feat to most), and only allows the conversion of the Power Attack penalty to an AC penalty during a charge. That feat is considered one of the most valuable fighter feats in the game. That said, mundanes could use the help; I’d definitely consider allowing a reverse Combat Expertise.

Comment: @KRyan: with *Tumble* synergy, *Fight Defensively* becomes +3 AC for -4 AR... and I believe there were some ways to even this out... but yeah, moot point if you cannot avoid Combat Expertise.

Comment: I thin there's situations where Combat Expertise is useful, albeit very situational: Whenever you miss with a 1 even by taking the -5, or anyway your base attack is huge compared to the enemies AC, but you need some extra defense, the feat is better then the total defense, because you can still attack. This s less useful to whoever lowers his To Hit for other reasons, of course.

Answer (score 2):

It's **almost always better to use Combat Expertise** in this situation.

There are a few third-party classes, and I think a few PrCs, that get special benefits when using total defense.  Those characters might have a tougher decision to make.  In normal play, though, if you need the AC, it's usually better to go ahead and take your attack(s) with the penalty than to sacrifice them.

(This assumes you're going to *either* use total defense *or* use Combat Expertise, and doesn't take options like *don't use either defensive option* into account.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a synergy between the *Tumble* skill and the *Fight Defensively* and *Total Defense* actions. If you have more than 5 ranks in *Tumble*, you get:

- +1 Dodge AC when fighting defensively
- +2 Dodge AC when using *Total Defense*

As a result, with a meager 5 ranks in *Tumble*, achievable by level 2, you get a total of +6 Dodge AC when using *Total Defense*.

At this point, it becomes:

- *Total Defense*: +6 Dodge AC, no retaliating
- *Combat Expertise*: +5 Dodge AC, -5 Attack Roll (damned by the cap, but already a heavy penalty)

It is also important to note that *Combat Expertise* is capped by BAB:

- a 3/4 BAB character (such as a Rogue) obtains +5 BAB at level 7th
- a 1/2 BAB character (such as a Wizard) obtains +5 BAB at level 10th

For those characters, *Combat Expertise* only comes into full effect very late compared to the synergy bonus of *Tumble* (if in class skill).

Comment: there is this, http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#superiorExpertise
but it costs another feat

Comment: @Wyrmwood: Yeah, and between a -10 penalty and no attack at all...

Comment: What on earth is “AR”? That’s not a standard term in 3.5 to my knowledge.

Comment: @KRyan: I use it for Attack Roll, let me edit that.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As @Wyrmwood pointed and I missed:

> assuming a BAB of 4 or higher

Then I will consider it as so from now on.

I believe the main advantage of ***Total Defense*** over ***Combat Expertise*** and ***Fighting Defensively*** is the possibility of a safer approach or crossing a threatened area generating AoO before your attack, specially with 5 ranks in *Tumble*.

***Total Defense*** is clearly a better option for those that need the extra AC now and are not threatening anyone and/or can't attack. Even more to those that also are in the threatening area of an enemy that you can't hit melee from your position (bigger enemy or reach weapons).

Imagine these scenarios:

**• Level 9:** Two Athach surprised the party in a closed space and you (a Rogue) are alone at the other side, with no way out except step between/alongside them. It would be hard to tumble all that threatening area  at this level, unless you have enough speed and confidence. However, you may use your standard action to get a +6 dodge bonus to AC and try to pass alive against the 2 AoO. A level 9 Rogue, for example, usually have an AC between 21 to 25 at level 9, with +6 she goes between 27 to 31 against the +16 to hit of the athaches (+12 in a full attack). You may not have enough speed to cross this huge area, but maybe enough to reach to cross one and stay close to the rest of the party (at least close enough for the cleric reach with Revivify).

**• Level 6:** An already hurt human Scout must cross the battle to reach the cleric to receive healing, but with 5 thugs on his way, even with his 40ft.(12m) speed, quick tumble while avoiding 5 AdO is too much (DC 33). Thanks to his Mobility feat (normal feat for as Scout at level 4 bonus feat) he already has +4 to AC against AdO for crossing this death corridor, using the Total Defense standard action, the aforementioned scout has +10 extra dodge bonus to his AC to escape his predicament and reach the healing mach..., I mean, the cleric.

If you change to people that can't tumble his way out and have **Combat Expertise** (Fighters, Crusaders etc), both scenario are still true, but they may have a reach weapon that allow them to use combat expertise from relative safety, but everything goes down when you give longspears (or spiked chains if you are really mean) to the ogres or fighting a Gargantuan Monstrous Centipede, basically anything with more reach than you.

Comment: @Wyrmwood I edited there to be up to your specifications. The two last paragraphs work at most levels.

Comment: Couldn't this simply say, "You can still use Total Defense when you are unable to attack"?

Comment: @Wyrmwood Yeah, I could but I thought the answer would be kind of lacking being so short. You got the gist of it fast but it's better for others that don't to explain it all with examples.

Comment: Yeah, but I had to read it like 7 times before I realized your point. Maybe a summary line at the beginning to explain.

Comment: @Wyrmwood I moved the last paragraph closer to the top and you may find it now faster to get the gist of it.

Comment: This is better, but I still don't think this clarifies the two positions. One, *when you are able to attack, clearly CE/FD is superior*, however, case two, *if you are unable to attack, you are unable to use CE/FD*, then TD isn't a *better* option, it's the *only* option.

Comment: @Wyrmwood It's not that you're unable to attack in all situations. You can attack the Ogres with Spiked Chains at the cost of an AdO, but I just don't think it is worth doing it. In that case is not the only option, is just the better option. It would be the only option if you need to cross a 30ft.(9m) gap that has 8 archers 80ft.(24m) away ready to shoot if you show your face.

Comment: What is an AdO? The defense bonus is the same with either strategy, and you give up attacking, including attacks of opportunity with Total Defense, and burn a standard action, so no matter what, TD is poorer. However, it's the only option when not attacking. Really, I still stand by my first assessment -the additional verbiage is superfluous and obfuscates the only valid point - *if you don't attack, then you have to use TD*.  Your answer implies incorrectly you could take a double move, but you can't, TD is a standard action.

Comment: @Wyrmwood "What is an AdO?" Oops, sorry. AdO is AoO (Attack of Opportunity) in my native language that slipped here.

Actually I never said anything about a double move, I'm aware of the fact that TD is a standard action. I just said that I think it is better to move in a threatened area with more AC than not. If the character is confident he can take a hit and keep fighting or can just blow the oppenent away after taking the AoO, TD would not be an optimal choice for such character. As such everything else, the dice will decide the result, no matter the choice is always a gamble.

Comment: @Wyrmwood The very question of yours depends entirely of the character in question. A fighter and a rogue will have different perspectives and approaches and what is trivial for one, is a life threatening experience for the other.

Comment: *better to move with more AC* - this is where your post is misleading. The AC bonus is the same for both strategies, *assuming a BAB of 4 or higher*. I must be missing *something* because you have two upvotes, but perhaps not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72246/discussion-between-wyrmwood-and-aguinaldo-silvestre).